# Search Pipe fails when getting data from MongoDB rather than Mock Data in Angular2

Tags: mongodb, rest, http, angular, angular2-services

Today I am trying to switch from using mock data stored in a `const` to using the same data stored on my local `MongoDB`, but I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./FoodListComponent class FoodListComponent - inline template:2:30 caused by: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
>       at SearchPipe.transform (search.pipe.ts:15)

The error occurs because of a search pipe on my `*ngFor` @ `inline template:2:30`

```
<div *ngFor="let food of foods | searchPipe: 'mySearchTerm'">
```

The error message is especially odd to me because the service is returning an `Observable`, not a `Promise`.

If I remove that search pipe then every thing works fine, but I have no search functionality. It's as if the template is compiling before the data gets there. **How can I correct this?**

**food-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Food } from '../../../interfaces/diet/food'
import { FoodsService } from '../../../services/foods/foods.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'food-list',
  templateUrl: './food-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./food-list.component.scss'],
  providers: [ WorkingDataService, FoodsService ]
})
export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  foods: Food[];
  constructor ( private _foodsService: FoodsService) {  }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    // this._foodsService.getFoods().subscribe(foods => this.foods = foods); // this worked fine
    this._foodsService.getMongoFoods().subscribe(foods => this.foods = foods);
  }
}
```

**foods.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Food } from '../../interfaces/diet/food'
import { FOODS } from './mock-foods';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class FoodsService {
  baseURL: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
  }

  getFoods(): Observable<Food[]> { // this worked with my search pipe
    return Observable.of(FOODS);   // I'm returning an observable to a const
  }

  getMongoFoods(): Observable<Food[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'api/foods')
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  // ... standard response and error handling functions
}
```

**search.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(foods: any[], mySearchTerm: string): any[] {

      let mySearchTerm = mySearchTerm.toUpperCase();

      foods = foods.filter(food => { // The failure hits here because foods isn't defined yet
        // my filter logic
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until your observable resolves itself, your foods array is undefined to start with in food-list.component.ts because you haven't initialised it:

`foods: Food[];`

if you change that to 
  `foods: Food[] = [];`
it should work.

Alternatively you can do a check for undefined at the start of your pipe, something like:

`if (!foods) return foods;`